# переносить предлоги на новую строку css || html

Tags: html, css

В верстке считается ошибкой не переносить предлоги и слова короче 3 букв. Как можно добиться переноса с помощью css? Или единственный и самый верный способ везде ставить br и прятать их на mobile-разрешении?

Пример: http://take.ms/kva9F

Comment: Вроде такая штука есть `word-wrap` - _Свойство word-wrap указывает, переносить или нет длинные слова, которые не помещаются по ширине в заданную область._

Comment: word-break - переносит, word-wrap - позволяет перенести длинное слово. Как можно **переносить предлоги, если они в конце строки?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предлагаю корректировать размещаемый текст, вручную или с помощью скрипта, так как список таких предлогов конечен. Суть корректировок в том, что вы между предлогом и словом вместо обычного пробела ставите неразрывный `&nbsp;`. Т.е. вместо `на улице` должно получиться `на&nbsp;улице`.

Comment: Да, так и приходится. Наверное это уже js-либа нужна, чтобы делать это автоматически.

Comment: Можете пользоваться Типографом, находится на сайте студии Лебедева.